# Explain program longer way

Tags: python

could somebody explain this longer way? I don't really understand that part of code, how it works. Could somebody write it out long way like: 
   if thing = "x"
   if thing = ...

```
thing = "x" if thing.lower() == "o" else "o"
```

Comment: `thing` is assigned `"x"` if `thing.lower()` is `"o"` (i.e. that segment of the line evaluates to `True`), otherwise it's assigned `"o"`.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to

```
if thing.lower() == "o":
    thing = "x"
else:
    thing = "o"
```